# Data from newly created .text file is not readable to third party application

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0

I have developed a windows application, which will read updated data from .jrn files(In an ATM Machine) and will be copy the text to a temporary text file "tempfile.txt".

There is another third party application called "POS Text Sender", which reads "tempfile.txt" and display the contents of it in a CCTV Camera.

The problem is that if I type directly something in the tempfile, the POS application will read it, but if my application writes text to "tempfile", I can see the same content as in the .jrn file in tempfile, but it is not reflected in the POS application when ever data is copied from newly generated file to tempfile.if restart the POS Text Sender after the first data copied to tempfile from newly generated file,POS Text sender will display the content til content from newly created file is written to tempfile

My application code is reading .jrn file using StreamReader and assigning it to a string variable and then writing it to  a tempfile using StreamWriter. What is the difference between manually typing  text on a file and .NET StreamWriter writing text to a file?

CODE:

```
 DateTime LastChecked = DateTime.Now;
 try
 {
     string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test", "*.jrn", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

     foreach (string file in files)
     {
         if (!fileList.Contains(file))
         {
             currentfilename = file;
             fileList.Add(file);
             copywarehouse(file);
             //do_some_processing();
             try
             {
                 // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
                 // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
                 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
                 {
                     currentcontent=sr.ReadToEnd();
                     // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
                     //// the file is reached.
                     //while ((currentcontent = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                     //{

                     //}
                     sr.Close();
                     //sr.Dispose();
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception)
             {
                 // Let the user know what went wrong.

             }
         }
     }

     //checking
     try
     {
         using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(currentfilename))
         {
             string currentfilecontent = sr.ReadToEnd();
             sr.Close();
             //sr.Dispose();
             if (currentfilecontent!=currentcontent)
             {
                 if (currentfilecontent.Contains(currentcontent))
                 {
                     string originalcontent = currentfilecontent.Substring(currentcontent.Length);
                     System.IO.StreamWriter filenew = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Test\tempfile.txt");

                     filenew.WriteLine(originalcontent);
                     filenew.Close();
                     currentcontent = currentfilecontent;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         // Let the user know what went wrong.
     }
```

`copywarehouse` method:

```
 private void copywarehouse(string filename)
 {
    string sourcePath = @"C:\Test";
    string targetPath = @"C:\Test";
    try
    {
       string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, filename);
       string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, "tempfile.txt");
       System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You should show the code that writes the file. I suspect that you are not closing appropriately the streamwriter.

Comment: *ATM Machine* The thing I have to type my PIN number in to?

Comment: @user975236 Where is the part where it writes to the temp file?

Comment: Have you tried comparing a manually-typed file, and one written by your application in a hex editor? If there is text in the application written file, but this other app can't read it, then I suspect it is the file encoding (it probably expects ASCII and .NET is writing UTF-8, would be my guess).

Comment: You should remove all of your empty catch and let the program show if it hit an exception. If there is something wrong in your file operations above you will never know the faulting point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check the following:

1. Is the generated file encoding same as the manually created file? (i.e. UTF-8/ANSI).
2. Are your constantly flushing the streamWriter's buffer? Or set the StreamWriter's AutoFlush property to true.
3. Is the StreamWriter opened with a WriteLock with no read allowed? In this case the other application may not be able to open your tempfile for read access.

**EDIT:**

Also, in the code you posted, you are comparing the tempFile data to current data, and if tempFile data is newer than current data, you are appending the temp file, which I think **should be vice versa.**

**Main change:**

```
using (StreamWriter filenew = new StreamWriter(fileDetail.TempFileName, true, Encoding.ASCII))
                                {
                                    filenew.WriteLine(newContent);
                                }
```

To know the correct encoding, just create a new tempFile, write something in the editor and save it. Open the file in notepad and do a "save as". This will display the current encoding in the bottom. Set that encoding in .NET code.

**If this does not work try (As recommended by shr):**

```
using (StreamWriter filenew = new StreamWriter(fileDetail.TempFileName, true, Encoding.ASCII))
                                {
                                    filenew.Write(newContent + "\r\n");
                                }
```

**Long Version:** (It may be a bit different than your code):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime LastChecked = DateTime.Now;

            IDictionary<string, FileDetails> fileDetails = new Dictionary<string, FileDetails>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            IList<string> tempFileList = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test", "*.jrn", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    string currentfilename = file;
                    string currentcontent = string.Empty;

                    if (!fileDetails.Keys.Contains(file))
                    {
                        fileDetails[file] = new FileDetails(copywarehouse(file));
                        //do_some_processing();
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
                        {
                            currentcontent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // Let the user know what went wrong.
                    }

                    fileDetails[file].AddContent(currentcontent);
                }

                //TODO: Check using the file modified time. Avoids unnecessary reading of file.
                foreach (var fileDetail in fileDetails.Values)
                {
                    //checking
                    try
                    {
                        string tempFileContent = string.Empty;
                        string currentcontent = fileDetail.GetContent();

                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileDetail.TempFileName))
                        {
                            tempFileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                            sr.Close();
                        }

                        if (!(0 == string.Compare(tempFileContent, currentcontent)))
                        {
                            if (currentcontent.Contains(tempFileContent))
                            {
                                string newContent = tempFileContent.Substring(currentcontent.Length);

                                using (StreamWriter filenew = new StreamWriter(fileDetail.TempFileName, true, Encoding.ASCII))
                                {
                                    filenew.WriteLine(newContent);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // Let the user know what went wrong.
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        private static string copywarehouse(string filename)
        {
            string sourcePath = @"C:\Test";
            string targetPath = @"C:\Test";

            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, filename);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, filename+ "tempfile.txt");

            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            return destFile;
        }

        internal class FileDetails
        {
            public string TempFileName { get; private set; }
            private StringBuilder _content;

            public FileDetails(string tempFileName)
            {
                TempFileName = tempFileName;
                _content = new StringBuilder();
            }

            public void AddContent(string content)
            {
                _content.Append(content);
            }

            public string GetContent()
            {
                return _content.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Can you change the copywarehouse to this and see it the problem persists:

```
         private void copywarehouse(string filename)
        {
            const string sourcePath = @"C:\Test";
            const string targetPath = @"C:\Test";
            try
            {
                string sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, filename);
                string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, "tempfile.txt");


                string currentcontent;
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(sourceFile))
                {
                    currentcontent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                using (var wr = new StreamWriter(destFile, false, Encoding.ASCII))
                {
                    wr.WriteLine(currentcontent);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: @user975236 I saw your code. But it does not have a mention of TextWriter anywhere. Also edit your question and add the TextWriter portion. Do not post it as an answer.

Comment: textwritter?..where do i need to add?

Comment: @user975236 Sorry I meant StreamWriter. The question has the code you posted. Just edit your question to also include the method that writes to the TempFile using StreamWriter.

Comment: please see my above code,i have used streamwriter to write my content to file

Comment: I added encoding using ASCII and carriage return,newline..when a new file is created in this folder,that content is not accessing POS,even it is written to tempfile,but when writting to existing file,some time is showing contents...

Comment: @user975236 Have you checked your logic that checks if new content available? Is it writing new content to the file? Are you checking the tempfile too often?

Comment: The contents copying to tempfile is the right content. ie.When ever new file creates or writing to existing file.tempfile is updating in correct format,but the problem,it is not accessing by POS Text Sender .When new file creates with data in directory,this data is showing in tempfile,but it is not accessing by POS Text sender.But When writing second time to this existing file,it will read the content from tempfile.

Comment: @user975236 Can you change your copywarehouse as per my answer? (I have put it at the end in EDIT2

Comment: I have tested it,but the same,POS Text Sender gets stopped when timer reads newly created file content...I really dont know what is the difference of manually typing into a file and Program copying content to file

Comment: @suhail Sorry Suhail but I think I may not be able to help you here. I am out of ideas here :)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is a CR+LF issue.
The POS expects the file to have line endings with CR+LF (Carriage Return (0x0D) + New line (0x0A)) combination.

The `filenew.WriteLine(originalcontent)` appends only the new line character. When you type, I think, you editor must be creating the CR+LF combination for all line endings.

I suggest you try `filenew.Write( originalcontent + "\r\n");`

Comment: I have tried this..but still POS is not reading.POS is reading the updated content of same file, but content copying from newly generated file stops POS display,if newly generated file data is copying to temporary file,then POS should restart

Answer (score 1):

One difference is that your application does not write to tempfile.txt directly but to another file and then copies that file to tempfile.txt.

Comment: The problem was with third party application,third party application was not monitoring contents from more than one file..thanks for sharing all of your knowledge here